# Using jsfiddle-linechart with scrollbar does not work

Tags: jsfiddle, linechart

The code in this [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jmpxgufu/) link doesn't work.

The result is :

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined at HTMLDocument.
> (flot-data.js:726) at j (jquery.min.js:2) at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

ok this is now working after downloading the ChartJS Stuff,

but not still this apears:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Line is not a function